# Emit from Observable and then make additional REST API call for more detail

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have two methods which do HTTP calls to Rest APIs. One is getProducts() which will return a array of products and the other is getProductsDetail() which can take that array as parameter and will return the array of products with additional fields populated.

I would like to call these two APIs in sequence, with getProductsDetail() depending on the result of getProducts(), but i would like my Observable to emit the result from getProducts() as soon as that is ready.  And then have getProductsDetail() emit with the extra detail when this call returns.

Is there a way to do this with an RxJS operator like concatMap or mergeMap?  I would like to have my template start to display as soon as possible, but fill in the extra data when this is available

UPDATE:

Hi, thanks for the replies!   I'm sorry I only pseudo code at the moment, but I think my initial attempt was going to be be something similar to what Authur had below

```
initProductsPage(): Observable<Products[]>{
this.productsService.getProducts().pipe(
  switchMap(
    (products: Products[]) => {
      // would like to also emit products here

      return this.productsService.getProductsDetail(products);
    }
  )
```

}

My understanding would be that in this case a subscriber to initProductsPage() would only recieve an output when getProductsDetail() returns.  I'd like to have that subscriber get the products while getProductsDetails() is executing.

Comment: This is by all means a well explained question, but could you show some code of what you've tried and ran into problems with?

Comment: I'm sure that you could achieve what you want using `switchMap` operator. This is a pipeable one, but I agree that we need the code in order to provide a more complete answer. My guess is that you could go like this:
 `productsDetails$ = this.products$.pipe(switchMap((products) => this.productService.getProductsDetail(products)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming both `getProducts()` and `getProductsDetail()` return an `Observable<Product[]>`, you could do something like this:

```
getProductsWithDetailsHydration(): Observable<Product[]> {
  const productsShared$ = this.getProducts().pipe(share()); // <- to share same GET products request.

  return merge(
    productsShared$, // <- 1st obs Gets and emits Products
    productsShared$.pipe( //<- 2nd obs Gets details using products response and emit Products with Details
      concatMap((products) => this.getProductsDetail(products))
    )
  );
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  i think this looks exactly like what i want.  However when i update my code to this i get the following error on the merge operator `Type OperatorFunction<unknown, unknown> is missing the following properties from type'Observable<Product[]>: _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.` 

Both statements inside the merge return `Observable<Product[]>`

Comment: be sure you are importing `merge` from `rxjs`, **not**  from `rxjs/operators`.

Comment: yah, i saw that being the solution when i googled the error, but my imports were already from `rxjs/operators`.  This is what i have at the moment `import { merge, concatMap, share } from 'rxjs/operators';`  I'm developing on Angular 11.1.2, RxJS 6.6.3, typescript 4.0.5

Comment: That's the problem, you should **not** use `rxjs/operators` for the merge import, you should import it like this:  `import { merge } from 'rxjs'`. Sorry if it wasn't clear enough before.

Comment: haha i would never have thought of trying it the other way!  Working perfectly now. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would have been from API end is to have a getProductDetail$() method. Which can get details for a single product. Then you could easily use `async` in the template itself and fill the template.

Example Template Code

```
<ng-container *ngIf="getProduct$() | async as product">
    // Some info on product
    <div>{{product.title}}</div>
    <ng-container *ngIf="getProductDetail$(product.id) | async as productDetail">
         // Some info on product details
        <div>{{productDetail.description}}</div>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: This would be a bad idea with default change detection strategy since the function bound to a structural directive `*ngIf` would be triggered for each change detection cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the better way to address this is by separating the two observables.

Then you could subscribe and get the values:

```
  // Class variables
  products: Products[];
  products$: Observable<Products[]>;
  productsDetails: ProductsDetails[];
  productsDetails$: Observable<ProductsDetails[]>;

  // Call OnInit or OnChanges depending of your needs
  initProductsPage(): void {
    // Initialize the observables
    this.products$ = this.productsService.getProducts();
    this.productsDetails$ = this.products$.pipe(
      switchMap((products) => this.getProductsDetail(products))
    );

    // Using take(1) to complete the observable after it gets the value
    this.products$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(products => {
      this.products = products;
    });

    // Using take(1) to complete the observable after it gets the value
    this.productsDetails$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(productsDetails => {
      this.productsDetails = productsDetails;
    });
  }
```

Then you could use `products` and `productsDetails` in your template.

Also you may use the observables directly on the template with `|async` and in this case the second part of the `initProductsPage()` wont be neccesary.

```
  // Class variables
  products: Products[];
  products$: Observable<Products[]>;
  productsDetails: ProductsDetails[];
  productsDetails$: Observable<ProductsDetails[]>;

  // Call OnInit or OnChanges depending of your needs
  initProductsPage(): void {
    // Initialize the observables
    this.products$ = this.productsService.getProducts();
    this.productsDetails$ = this.products$.pipe(
      switchMap((products) => this.getProductsDetail(products))
    );
  }
```